# Conversion from type DBNull to type String is not valid in vb.net

Tags: string, vb.net, vb.net-2010, dbnull

Please the solution I have an error "Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' because the pathhelper column has a null value

```
Private Sub gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CustomColumnDataEventArgs) Handles GridView1.CustomUnboundColumnData
        If e.Column.FieldName = "Image" AndAlso e.IsGetData Then
            Dim view As GridView = TryCast(sender, GridView)

            Dim colorName As String = CStr(view.GetListSourceRowCellValue(e.ListSourceRowIndex, "Color"))
            Dim fileName As String = GetFileName(colorName).ToLower()
            ***Dim PATHHELPER As String = CStr(view.GetListSourceRowCellValue(e.ListSourceRowIndex, "Pathhelper")) 'error this line***


            If (Not Images.ContainsKey(fileName)) Then
                Dim img As Image = Nothing
                Try
                    Dim filePath As String = DevExpress.Utils.FilesHelper.FindingFileName(parentpathimage & PATHHELPER, fileName, False)
                    img = Image.FromFile(filePath)
                Catch
                End Try
                Images.Add(fileName, img)
            End If
            e.Value = Images(fileName)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: viewdatabase]

Comment: If the data contains NULLs then write code to handle that. Stop assuming that there's a `String` present when you know there might not be. If you had a bucket that might contain or might not, would you just stick a brush in it and start painting a wall? Of course you wouldn't, because that would be ludicrous. You would check the bucket first to see whether it had paint in it and only paint with it if it did. Why do you think that the same obvious logic wouldn't apply here?

Comment: Could use String.IsNullOrEmpty(String) to test the value before hand and take appropriate steps

Comment: @Hursey , Can you answer as your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the DBNull class Value property for comparison.

```
Dim PATHHELPER As String
If Not DBNull.Value.Equals(View.GetListSourceRowCellValue(e.ListSourceRowIndex, "Pathhelper")) Then
    PATHHELPER = CStr(View.GetListSourceRowCellValue(e.ListSourceRowIndex, "Pathhelper"))
Else
    PATHHELPER = String.Empty 'or Nothing depending what comes next.
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this I think should do the trick.  Probably far better ways to do it but this is the way I would

```
Dim PATHHELPER as String = String.Empty
If view.GetListSourceRowCellValue(e.ListSourceRowIndex, "Pathhelper") <> DBNull.Value Then
    PATHHELPER = view.GetListSourceRowCellValue(e.ListSourceRowIndex, "Pathhelper").ToString
End if
```

Comment: ,`If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(view.GetListSourceRowCellValue(e.ListSourceRowIndex, "Pathhelper")) Then' still error in this code.

Comment: Yeah, penny dropped.  Hit the submit same time as you I guess

Comment: `Operator '<>' is not defined for string "\New folder" and type 'DBNull'.` . Still problem